# Python - Filter dataframe based on condition about different time for each of dates

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, datetime

I have `date_time_df` dataframe with `date_time` column as like this one:

```
import datetime
date_time_df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':[datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 9, 15, 3),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 9, 9, 50, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 9, 10, 50, 3),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 9, 16, 50, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 9, 20, 30, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 8, 9, 50, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 8, 10, 50, 3),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 8, 16, 50, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 8, 20, 30, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 7, 10, 50, 3),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 7, 16, 50, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 6, 16, 50, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 6, 20, 30, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 5, 9, 50, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 5, 20, 30, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 4, 16, 50, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 3, 9, 50, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 3, 10, 50, 3),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 3, 16, 50, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 2, 9, 50, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 2, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 10, 45, 3),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 20, 30, 0)]})
```

I need to sort it by the following conditions:

1. for each date select only one time-slot around 10 hours (`time >= 10` hours);
2. in case if for some date there is only one timeslot -> keep it in case if it after 10 h (i.e `time >=10` hours);
3. if date doesn't have timeslot around 10 h, include the next one (it might be equals `16:50` or `20:30` or `17:00` in the above example)

I tried to solve it by the following steps:

1. split `date_time_df` data frame to date, time columns. So, `date_time_df` has 3 columns as like `['date_time', 'date', 'time']`
2. create new `gr_df` as a result of:

```
gr_df  = date_time_df.groupby('date')['time'].nunique().reset_index()
gr_df.rename(columns={'time':'count_timeslots'}, inplace=True)
```

3. filter `gr_df` and select rows which have only one timeslot:

```
dates_with_one_timeslot = list(gr_df[gr_df['count_timeslots']==1].date_time.unique())
```

4. filter `gr_df` and select rows which have slot around 10 hours:

```
req_timeslots = list(date_time_df[date_time_df['time'].dt.strftime('%H')=='10'].date_time.unique())
```

5. I don't have idea of How to cover condition for dates which doesn't have times lot around 10 hours, but it has next one after 10h (time might be equals `16:50` or `20:30` or `17:00`)

Correct output:

```
result_lst = [
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 9, 10, 50, 3),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 8, 10, 50, 3),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 7, 10, 50, 3),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 6, 16, 50, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 5, 20, 30, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 4, 16, 50, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 3, 10, 50, 3),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 2, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 10, 45, 3)
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the rows where `hour` is greater than or equal to `10` then sort the values by `date_time` in ascending order and drop duplicates by `date` component

```
m = df['date_time'].dt.hour >= 10
df['date'] = df['date_time'].dt.date
df[m].sort_values('date_time').drop_duplicates('date')
```

---

```
             date_time        date
21 2020-07-01 10:45:03  2020-07-01
20 2020-07-02 17:00:00  2020-07-02
17 2020-07-03 10:50:03  2020-07-03
15 2020-07-04 16:50:00  2020-07-04
14 2020-07-05 20:30:00  2020-07-05
11 2020-07-06 16:50:00  2020-07-06
9  2020-07-07 10:50:03  2020-07-07
6  2020-07-08 10:50:03  2020-07-08
2  2020-07-09 10:50:03  2020-07-09
```